# Updating a column in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

(Using PL/SQL anonymous program block)
I have a table tblROUTE2 of Mexican state highways:

```
+-----------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
|      TYPE       | ADMN_CLASS | TOLL_RD | RTE_NUM1 | RTE_NUM2 |         STATEROUTE         | LENGTH_KM |  STATE |
+-----------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
| Paved Undivided | Federal    | N       |       81 |          | Tamaulipas Federal Hwy  81 | 124.551   |  NULL  |
| Paved Undivided | Federal    | N       |      130 |          | Hidalgo Federal Hwy 130    | 76.347    |  NULL  |
| Paved Undivided | Federal    | N       |      130 |          | Mexico Federal Hwy 130     | 68.028    |  NULL  |
+-----------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+----------------------------+-----------+--------+
```

and tblSTATE2 of Mexican states:

```
+------+-----------------------+---------+-----------+
| CODE |         NAME          | POP1990 | AREA_SQMI |
+------+-----------------------+---------+-----------+
| MX02 | Baja California Norte | 1660855 | 28002.325 |
| MX03 | Baja California Sur   |  317764 | 27898.191 |
| MX18 | Nayarit               |  824643 | 10547.762 |
+------+-----------------------+---------+-----------+
```

I need to update the *STATE* field in tblROUTE2 with the *CODE* field found in tblSTATE2, based on the route name in tblROUTE2. Basically, I need to somehow take the first string or two (some routes have two names)-- before the string 'Federal'-- of the *STATEROUTE* field in tblROUTE2 and make sure it matches with the string in the *NAME* field in tblSTATE2. Then since the states are matched with a CODE, update those codes in the *STATE* field of tblROUTE2.

I have started a code:

```
DECLARE
  state_code         
     tblROUTE2.STATE%TYPE;
  state_name   
     tblSTATE2.NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT STATE, NAME
    INTO state_code
    FROM tblROUTE2 r, tblSTATE2 s
   WHERE STATEROUTE LIKE '%Federal';
END;
```

As well, I will need to remove the state name from the route name. For example, the string in *STATEROUTE* 'Tamaulipas Federal Hwy' becomes 'Federal Hwy'. I have started a code, not sure if it's right:

```
UPDATE tblROUTE2
SET STATEROUTE = TRIM(LEADING FROM 'Federal');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) update :

```
MERGE INTO tblROUTE2 A
USING
(
    SELECT CODE, NAME  FROM tblSTATE2
) B 
ON 
(
    upper(SUBSTR(A.STATEROUTE, 0, INSTR(UPPER(A.STATEROUTE), UPPER('FEDERAL'))-2)) = upper(B.NAME)
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET A.STATE = B.CODE;
```

Here in [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c25dc/1) I've replicated your tables and added additional record where `STATEROUTE` matches one of the records in `NAME`. Although Fiddle return an error, I ran it in my Oracle DB, and one record was updated correctly as the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am getting a message saying "0 rows merged." I am trying to understand the line `SUBSTR(A.STATEROUTE, 0, INSTR(UPPER(A.STATEROUTE), UPPER('FEDERAL'))-1) = B.NAME`. Is it saying to substract the string in STATEROUTE starting from 0 index up to the word Federal?

Comment: @Toronto23 yes, so `STATEROUTE` in the first row, will be `Tamaulipas`. Since nothing match `Tamaulipas` in `tblSTATE2` in `NAME` column, then it won't update anything.

Comment: @Toronto23 I've replicated your tables with one additional row, in order to create a match. Check the link provided.

Comment: I tried it with the -2 instead and it worked for most of the records. The problem is that I just noticed that some of the records are called "Distrito Federal Federal Hwy 95" (thus two "Federal") and some records are called "Sinaloa State Hwy 1" (thus no "Federal"). STATE code are coming up as NULL for those records

Comment: I'm also trying to rewrite the code to make it PL/SQL language with a WHERE statement

Comment: @Toronto23 So for those without `Federal`, what part you need to extract? I thought you just need to extract the string before the word `FEDERAL`, but if there is not `FEDERAL`, then based on what?. Your question is not consistent here. Clarify